# Xamarin VerticalTextView dont show text

Tags: android, xamarin.android, textview

I'm using following code for VerticalTextView, It works when the text is in english, but nothing when the text is in hebrew.
If i mix, then it shows when the text starts with english and then continues with hebrew, but not the other way around.
I thought its about `TextDirection` but i dont see any change with setting it to ltr (for example).
Any ideas?

https://gist.github.com/trinnguyen/358d5adb3bb964962e4af560ab0759ae

Comment: I created a blank app with this custom control, the fonts are shown correctly. Could you please try it with other emulator/deivce?

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT, I tried on different device and got the same results. Can you share your code?

Comment: You can try my demo [here](https://github.com/elvisxia/VerticalTextViewSample).